# Seriously outages on my network, is there a conflict somewhere?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, dhcp

I'm IT on a company which is already set up by an old IT who left and is not reachable. According to people at the company, they have had (and are having) internet outages.

So, first the setup:

I have a main router (MR) that is a MicroTik with RouterOS with private Lan ip = 192.168.123.254

This MR creates a wireless network (WPA2-AES, 2.4GHZ) with DHCP 192.168.123.[201-250]. SSID = "Wireless1"

Now, there are 2 more wifi routers throughout the place, both connected via ethernet to the MR

Extra Router 1 (ER1) - This is a Unifi AP-LR. Has ip 192.168.123.206, subnet 255.255.255.0, gateway 192.168.123.254, DNS = country's regional dns. SSID = "Wireless2". 2.4Ghz too.

Question: This router has a static IP as you can see, which is INSIDE the DHCP range of the MR. On the MR, I saw that the ip was made static for the MAC address of this router. 1) Is that okay, or should I change the IP of this router to be OUTSIDE the DHCP range of MR?

Also: It has a LAN network configured. Subnet 192.168.1.1/24, DHCP = 192.168.1.[6-254]. I have no idea why this is enabled or why it exists. As it is on the same cable network as MR no one would connect via ethernet to it in the first place. Was this setup by the previous IT just in case? Am i missing the point?

Extra Router 2 -

A TP-LINK wifi router. This one is 5GHZ only. SSID = "Wireless3". Static ip = 192.168.123.10. Gateway = 192.168.123.254. DNS = country's regional dns.

2) I have a situation where often users will connect to "Wireless3" but have no internet. A quick ipconfig will show them having an ip of 194.168.100.x instead of 192.168.123.x. I can't figure out why don't they automatically aquire an ip from the DHCP server. I need to manually do ipconfig/release -> ipconfig/renew in console, or fix a static ip for them on their device. Does someone know why this could be?

Thank you in advance, this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Your internet is most probably broken because of IP address conflicts.  Of specific note, your DHCP server is handing out IP addresses used by static devices. I expect you also have more then 1 DHCP server active.

1. Moving all the routers so they sit at the top of the network range (ie 192.168.123.249-254)
2. Reconfiguring all except for 1 router as a switch/access point.  (You
   can do this by turning off DHCP and ignoring the WAN port and ensuring
   other devices are only plugged in to the LAN ports.
3. IMPORTANT - Turn off DHCP on all devices except the router.
4. Ensure the DHCP range does not overlap with any devices.
   192.168.123.100-200 is commonly used (although I prefer 192.168.123.65-127
   for subnetting purposes).